# Fedex/UPS Published vs Negotiated Rates huge discrepancy?

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, fedex, ups

How are these rates calculated at all and is there any control over what gets published on our site in terms of shipping rates? Or rather, where is that controlled to begin with?

I've got the APIs and all that plugged into the Magento backend, and this is what I get for shipping estimates, for example:

http://prntscr.com/6x7qyt

But then when I check the same address in UPS/Fedex, I get a shipping cost that's quite higher (so we're losing money on shipping, pretty much):

http://prntscr.com/6x7qys

What's going on?

Shouldn't these two be the same, at the very least?

If there was a discrepancy of a few cents, I'd understand, but almost double the amount?

Isn't there more to this in terms of control, what gets pulled, which rates, or is it something to do with the Fedex/UPS API and settings?

I'm on v1.8.0.0

Thanks.

Comment: Don't confuse with Normal rates and your rates. If you are a customer the price is standard like normal rates, but if you are a merchant some credit points you have that's what the price is low compared than normal price. Its based on your logistics dept.